# What options does a player have if the club carries out the threat of 'Rot in reserves'?

Tags: rules, football, transfer

If a player is under contract, and is obviously the first choice player for the team, but is forced to play in reserves due to conflict with the management, what options does he have to get out of the situation?

Few years back when Ferguson had made a statement saying Glazers were more likely to let Cristiano Ronaldo rot in reserves rather than be allowed to go to Madrid, there were some reports saying that it wasn't possible for the club to do so.

Apart from negotiating with the club or waiting for a very large transfer bid, what other options does a player have in case he ends up in such a situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player can put in a transfer request. But the club is under no obligation to let him go. The player must either attempt to patch things up with the management or be resigned to sitting on the sidelines. In this situation, generally, a player good enough to be in the first team would like to have as much playing time as possible. A recent example would be Saido Berahino with West Bromwich Albion. He put in an official transfer request. But the club refused to let him go. They rejected all the transfer offers they recieved for Berahino. He plays for the club in the Barclays Premier League right now, but he is not a regular first team starter, generally coming on as a substitute.

Comment: No I think there is another option involving CAS... I believe David Albelda was trying to look such a route of leaving the club at Valencia, but midway through the dispute, the manager got changed and Albelda was reinstated in the first team. I couldn't find any details on this case on Google though, but I believe during Ronaldo situation it was specified by some newspaper that United wont be able to enforce their threat.

Comment: I guess you're right. But going to CAS doesn't guarantee a first team spot. CAS can rule either way. Also, no club will want a player who is causing disharmony to be part of the first team. If he is an especially good player, the club will want to settle things as quickly as possible so they can make use of his skills. Unless it is a very dire situation, the player ends up getting his way generally.